# Is it a good way of working with ETL, if I use joins in the table input step?

Tags: join, etl, data-warehouse

I am wondering if it is the correct way of working with ETL by using a join (in my case I use 3 joins to get the desired values) in the **table input step** in my transformation. Or is there a better way? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As it is often the case: the answer depends on your environment. For instance, if you have a fast changing source system and lots of transformations with longer durations, first copying the needed information into a staging database can help you create reproducible results through all transformations involved. Directly joining tables from the source system can in that case create different results for two transformations running one after the other.

If you have a timeframe where your source system doesn't change much or at all - or if you need that information only in this single transformation - joining the tables may be no problem at all.

From a technical point of view there is nothing to say against joins (actually there are arguments *for* joins, especially performance). Comprehensibility is another matter, and here again your specific environment matters. ETL processes are often badly documented and working on a transformation that has been created years ago by someone else can be either easy or a complete pain. If your joins make sense from a technical perspective and you obtain your data from a consistent source, I don't see why you shouldn't use them. They should always be much faster than lookup steps in an ETL transformation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation